# Getting a "CPU over temperature error", but temperatures seem to be normal

Tags: troubleshooting, temperature, reset, build

I built a PC with the following parts:

- CPU: i5-2500
- Motherboard: Asus P8H67-M EVO rev 3.0
- RAM: G-Skill Ripjaws Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3 1333
- Video: GTX 560-Ti 1GB
- I used a crappy (but functioning) old case and a 500W Powercooler supply. The rig also includes 3 HDs and a DVD-RW.

Whenever I push the system mildly it resets right away (looks more like power off/power on) and gives me a "CPU over temperature error".

However, the BIOS always reports <65ºC for the CPU at the moment of the reset, same as Core Temp and RealTemp. This is RealTemp's log since launching BF3 until the reset, just over one minute as you can see:

[image]

Just to be sure I've checked the CPU cooler and reapplied the thermal paste twice, but nothing changed. I'm not overclocking at all.

What am I missing here? Could it be that the old power supply is generating this error? Maybe the motherboard isn't reporting temperatures correctly? I don't have any clue on how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your power supply is even a bit older, it could have fairly substantial falloff (up to about 15%-25%) to where you're meeting your power budget when running basic tasks but under load can't deliver. Following that logic even mild exertion of the system is going to cause it to brown-out, it's probably spazzy and obviously not dying properly so I wouldn't be surprised if it's not throwing the correct error.  I would expect that this is the main problem and not an over temperature error.

My general rule of thumb is if I'm using a power supply on a gaming system and not going to be replacing that psu for more than a year to a year and a half that I overshoot the base power budget by about 30-50% since it'll be putting your psu under fairly considerable strain on a regular basis breakdown will be something that will have to be worried about.